# Automatically check parents (in a taxonomy) when child is selected

Tags: customization, categories, taxonomy

On my website I have a custom taxonomy which contains a lot of parents, children, subchildren etc. Because of this, it is really long to manually find what I want, so do you know if there is a way to automatically tick all the parents when you tick a child ? An exemple :
I have a taxonomy which lists regions of the world :

-Africa

-Europe

--France

---Paris

-America

And what I would like here is France and Europe automatically ticked if I manually tick Paris. Does someone know how to do this ? Thanks !

NB : The only thing I found which could be really helpful is this code to paste https://gist.github.com/georgestephanis/6869291 but does it work and where to paste it ? Thanks !

Comment: That code should work; as to where to put it, that depends.  Are you building a theme, are you using a child theme, are you building a plugin?  What you need to do is put that code snippet you linked to in a `filename.js` file that enqueues/gets added in the admin side of your site.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your reply ! I'm actually using Elementor pro on a custom post type I created with CPT UI which is linked to 4 taxonomies. And I'd like to put this functionality on one of them.